# Why does my glitter material look worse when I bake it's map?

Tags: materials, shaders, baking

Why does my glitter material not look as shiny once I bake the maps?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRZXGbiXYHc

I used the above tutorial if that matters.
The maps I baked are diffuse, metallic, normal, and roughness.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review so it can be reopened.